# How do I count number of spaces, vowels, and characters?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
public class counter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int space = 0,vowel = 0,chara = 0,i;
        System.out.println(" Enter String ");
        String s =in.nextLine();
        for( i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = in.next().charAt(i);
            if(ch == ' ')
                space++;
            if(ch == 'e' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                vowel++;
            else
                chara++;
            System.out.println("Number of Vowels = "+vowel);
            System.out.println("Number of Spaces = "+space);
            System.out.println("Number of Char   = "+chara);

        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem? I have put three counters to count. I am coding in Eclipse and whenever I check the console I am not able to count the characters. It is just accepting inputs and not doing anything else.

Comment: Why are you using `in.next().charAt(i)` if you already asked user for data which you stored in `String s`?

Comment: Also don't print statistics in each iteration. Do it after you calculate them (after loop).

Comment: BTW can you provide example of expected output for `hello world` input? I am especially interested in amount of `chara` you expect, is it 10 (amount of all non-space characters) or 7 (amount of non-space and non-vowels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of typo errors. Change your code with,

```
String s = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

And

```
char ch = s.charAt(i);
```

And

```
if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
```

---

In your code you are using lowercase letters to compare with the user input. So you should convert the user input to lower case first. Your current code ignores all uppercase vowels(E, A, I ...). Use `toLowerCase()`.

By using `in.next()` the `Scanner` is waiting for an input. Since you have already taken an input using `nextLine()` you can use that.

Next one is obviously a typographical error. Vowels are A, E, I, O, U.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `char ch = in.next().charAt(i);`, and replace the other instances of `ch` with `s.charAt(i)`

The first `charAt` check should also be `a`, you have `e` twice.

Then move `System.out.println...` outside of the loop.

[**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/jNdGhD)

Comment: It would be more efficient (and simpler) to simply change `char ch = in.next().charAt(i);` to `char ch = s.charAt(i);` There's no reason to repeatedly invoke `s.charAt(i)`, since within each iteration it returns the save value every time.

Comment: @TedHopp yes, you're correct. I was more just showing the OP what they did wrong, and one way to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `s = in.next().charAt(i);`to `String s =in.nextLine()` and put `System.out.println`part outside of for loop.

Also there is double 'e' (with the help of @Ted Hopp):

`ch == 'e' || ch == 'e'` to `ch == 'e' || ch == 'a'`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int space = 0,vowel = 0,chara = 0,i;
    System.out.println(" Enter String ");
    String s =in.nextLine();

    for( i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if(ch == ' ')
         space++;
        if(ch == 'e' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
            vowel++;
        else
        chara++;


    }
    System.out.println("Number of Vowels = "+vowel);
    System.out.println("Number of Spaces = "+space);
    System.out.println("Number of Char   = "+chara);
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks ok - but you need to provide some comments on what you changed. Code-only answers aren't too helpful.

Comment: There's still a bug: OP's code has a typo and does not check for the vowel `'a'`; that hasn't been fixed here.

Comment: @Hülya it's not a warning; more of a suggestion :)

Comment: Suggestions are helpful for me so i am thankful :) It's only a week since i am here but sometimes comments are not pleasant, so i am trying to learn as fast as i can.